# Run vba code if Excel opens invisible Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to have powershell open an Excel file. The workbook should then run the following vba code on startup:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Number").Range("A2") = Worksheets("Number").Range("A2") + 1
End Sub
```

this should then kickoff this piece of code to refresh pivot tables.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

This works well if I set $Excel.visible = $true, but when I set $Excel.visible = $false it no longer works. Apparently it does not register Excel as opening when it is invisible? How do I get it to work? I've also tried to refresh the pivot tables with $Workbook.RefreshAll() (hashed out now), but this also does not work when Excel is invisible.

```
Param(
   $Source = “Path\input.xlsm”,
   #$worksheet1 = “Pivot”,
   $range1 = “A1:EZ1”,
   $Output = “Path\output.xlsx”
   #$worksheet2 = "Output"
   #$range2 = “G1”
   ) #end param
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false

$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($Source)
#$Workbook.RefreshAll()

$WorkbookOutput = $excel.Workbooks.open($Output)
$Excel.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$i = 1

foreach ($sheet in ($workbook.Worksheets | Where-Object {$_.Visible -eq -1 }))

 {
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item($i)
$worksheet.activate() 
$wksname = $worksheet.name
Write-Output $wksname
$range = $WorkSheet.Range($range1).EntireColumn
$range.Copy() | out-null
#$Excel.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$WorksheetOutput = $WorkbookOutput.WorkSheets.item($wksname)
$worksheetOutput.activate()
#$Range = $Worksheet.Range($range2)
$WorksheetOutput.Range($range1).PasteSpecial(-4163)
$i++
Write-Output $i
}
$WorkbookOutput.Save() 
$Excel.Quit()
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: New code using module as suggested:

```
Set-Location 'C:\Users\Stephan\Documents\Power BI\Excel'

$Source = 'MonthlyConsSalesPerItemNew.xlsm'
$Output = 'Output\MonthlyConsSalesPerItemNew.xlsx'
$range1 = “A1:EZ1” 
$excel = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $Source
$excelOutput = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $Output
$Workbook = $Source
$WorkbookOutput = $Output

$i = 1

foreach ($sheet in ($workbook.Worksheets | Where-Object {$_.Visible -eq -1 }))

 {


$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item($i)
$worksheet.activate() 
$wksname = $worksheet.name
Write-Output $wksname
$range = $WorkSheet.Range($range1).EntireColumn
$range.Copy() | out-null
#$Excel.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$WorksheetOutput = $WorkbookOutput.WorkSheets.item($wksname)
$worksheetOutput.activate()
#$Range = $Worksheet.Range($range2)
$WorksheetOutput.Range($range1).PasteSpecial(-4163)
$i++
Write-Output $i


}

Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $excel -NoSave
Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $excelOutput -Show
```

error:

```
Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "Error saving file C:\Users\Stephan\Documents\Power BI\Excel\Output\MonthlyConsSalesPerItemNew.xlsx"
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.1.2\Public\Close-ExcelPackage.ps1:27 char:29
+             else           {$ExcelPackage.Save()          }
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

Code Sample 3:

```
Param(
   $Source = “C:\Users\Stephan\Documents\Power BI\Excel\BackorderSummarized.xlsm”,
   #$worksheet1 = “Pivot”,
   $range1 = “A1:EZ1”,
   $Output = “C:\Users\Stephan\Documents\Power BI\Excel\Output\BackorderSummarized.xlsx”
   #$worksheet2 = "Output"
   #$range2 = “G1”
   ) #end param
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false

$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($Source)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.Sheets.Item("Number")
$wksname = $Excelworksheet.name
Write-Output $wksname

$Workbook.RefreshAll()
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
$Workbook.Save() 

$WorkbookOutput = $excel.Workbooks.open($Output)

$Excel.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$i = 1
```

Thanks as always.

Comment: As a side note: is downloading the Excel module an option for you? Super advanced module with **tons** of capabilities.

Comment: I have had some success using the `ImportExcel` module. `Find-Module -Name ImportExcel`

Comment: Hi, I have installed the module, but unsure how to proceed from there?

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala I have edited my post with new code using module. Having an issue with saving and refresh still does not seem to work.

Comment: with the excel window closed it's probably not pumping the events try adding `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` and `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()`

Comment: Hi @Gregory. Thank you for your reply. I tried doing what you asked, but VBA code still does not kick off. Perhaps I am adding the pieces of code in the wrong place? I added them after $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false Thanks.

Comment: `Workbook_Open()` and `Workbook_Change()` are workbook events, so you'd need to `DoEvents()` after your code opens and/or changes the workbook...

Comment: Hi Gregory, Sorry I'm such a noob. I edited my post with the relevant part of the code, but it's still not working if $excel.visible - false. I even have it activating the specific worksheet, which works but still does not kick off the vba code.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the issue where the Excel data source doesn't refresh when Excel's application window is set to invisible. This could possibly be due to a number of differences in your data source vs my test one; however I believe it is more likely due to the state of the `CutCopyMode` at the end of your code.

My test setup:

- Windows Powershell 5.1 64-Bit
- Windows 10
- Excel 2010 32-Bit
- SourceBook.xlsx:

  - Sheet1 = "ogData"
- LinkedBook.xlsm: `Workbook_Open()`

  - Sheet1 = "OnChangeSheet": `Worksheet_Change()`
  - Sheet2 = "LinkedTableSheet"
- DestBook.xlsx

  - Sheet1 = "Sheet1"

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("OnChangeSheet").Range("A2").Value2 = Worksheets("OnChangeSheet").Range("A2").Value2 + 1
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

My PS session walkthrough

```
PS C:\working> ps excel -ea SilentlyContinue
PS C:\working> ls


    Directory: C:\working


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         1/18/2022   1:00 PM           7878 DestBook.xlsx
-a----         1/18/2022   1:18 PM          16905 LinkedBook.xlsm
-a----         1/18/2022   1:18 PM           7933 SourceBook.xlsx


PS C:\working> $xl = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
PS C:\working> $xl.Visible       = $false
PS C:\working> $xl.DisplayAlerts = $false
PS C:\working> $DontSave         = $false
PS C:\working> $xlPasteValues    = -4163
PS C:\working>
PS C:\working> $wbSource = $xl.Workbooks.Open((Resolve-Path .\SourceBook.xlsx))
PS C:\working> $wbSource.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2').value2
Old Value
PS C:\working> $wbSource.Close($DontSave); rv wbSource
PS C:\working> $wbLinked = $xl.Workbooks.Open((Resolve-Path .\LinkedBook.xlsm))
PS C:\working> $wbLinked.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2').value2
1
PS C:\working> $wbLinked.Worksheets.Item(2).Range('A2').value2
Old Value
PS C:\working> $wbLinked.Save()
PS C:\working> $wbLinked.Close()
PS C:\working> rv wbLinked
PS C:\working>
PS C:\working> $wbSource = $xl.Workbooks.Open((Resolve-Path .\SourceBook.xlsx))
PS C:\working> $wbSource.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2').value2 = 'New Value'
PS C:\working> $wbSource.Save(); $wbSource.Close(); rv wbSource
PS C:\working>
PS C:\working> $wbLinked = $xl.Workbooks.Open((Resolve-Path .\LinkedBook.xlsm))
PS C:\working> $wbLinked.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2').value2
2
PS C:\working> $wbLinked.Worksheets.Item(2).Range('A2').value2
New Value
PS C:\working>
PS C:\working> $wbDest = $xl.Workbooks.Open((Resolve-Path .\DestBook.xlsx))
PS C:\working> $null = $wbLinked.Worksheets.Item(2).Range('A1:C1').EntireColumn.Copy()
PS C:\working> $wbDest.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2').value2
Historic Value
PS C:\working> $null = $wbDest.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A1').PasteSpecial($xlPasteValues)
PS C:\working> $wbDest.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2').value2
New Value
PS C:\working> $wbDest.Save(); $wbDest.Close(); rv wbDest
PS C:\working>
PS C:\working> $null = $wbLinked.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2').Copy(
>>    $wbLinked.Worksheets.Item(1).Range('A2')
>> )    # <-------- After final PasteSpecial() copy something benign to itself to clear the Application.CutCopyMode
PS C:\working> $wbLinked.Save(); $wbLinked.Close(); rv wbLinked
PS C:\working>
PS C:\working> $xl.Quit()
PS C:\working> ps excel -ea SilentlyContinue

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    496      45    18800      42268       1.83  21240   1 EXCEL


PS C:\working> [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($xl)
0
PS C:\working> ps excel -ea SilentlyContinue
PS C:\working> rv xl
PS C:\working>
```

Sorry about the whole `DoEvents()` comment; I remember that was a solution I had to go to a long time ago, but my guess it was more of a Win7/Excel 2003 issue and has since been bug-fixed as it does not appear as though it's needed here.

Moreover your VBA code appears to be doing the same thing that the `Data(RibbonTab)>Connections(Button)>Properties...(Button)>Refresh data when opening the file(CheckBox)` was designed to do, you may want to try that out and see if it's the easy answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for your reply. I tried using the Refresh data on open option before, but then the refresh doesn't work whether the excel is visible or not. I went back to basic, and made a simple pivot table, changed the input data manually and saved it without refreshing the pivot table.  When I then run the script it does refresh and copy. So now I am thinking it might have to do with the connection to Power BI model? Perhaps credentials are lost because it does not open the file or something?

Comment: Forgot to add, I'm running Excel 365 on Windows 10, Powershell ISE

Comment: @Smid sorry, I'm not much help with Power BI and Office 365; however it sounds like your problem may be more with the pivot table than with getting the VBA to run. You could try calling the `Worksheet.PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh` from either VBA or Powershell and see if that works; otherwise you'll probably have better luck asking a new question focused on the pivot table itself